# Spring: two database configurations online/offline

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there a method to have two configurations that automatically use one when online and another when local?

I mean two connections saved, one for the online version (when I try my website on another server) and one for my local tests...

Sorry for my bad english, I hope that someone can understand what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

I assume that your database beans are defined in a spring context file.

You have 2 choices:

- You can either put the online and offline beans in separate contexts and load them depending upon an environment variable
- Or you can simply pass the context files as parameters to your application and fire up spring manually